# React.memo component re-rendering without checking isEquals when expected

Tags: reactjs

**Edit:** Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-silence-5n4pv Why does pressing the button re-render all the cells, but scrolling not?

I'm trying to improve performance, so I've extracted a component into something with simple props that's more `React.memo` friendly:

```
interface DataTableCellProps {
  header: string;
  value: string;
  isRepeatedValue: boolean;
  width: number;
}

const DataCell = styled.div<{ width: number; isRepeatedValue: boolean }>`
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  width: ${props => props.width}px;
  color: ${props => (props.isRepeatedValue ? grey : lightGrey)};
  display: flex;
`;

/** Data table cells. A pure component that can be memoised easily (all props are simple types) */
const DataTableCell = React.memo(
  (props: DataTableCellProps) => {
    console.log("Rendering");
    return (
      <DataCell
        role="cell"
        area-header={props.header}
        width={props.width}
        isRepeatedValue={props.isRepeatedValue}
      >
        <Tooltip title={props.value} placement="bottom-start" enterDelay={500}>
          <span className="text-truncate">{props.value}</span>
        </Tooltip>
      </DataCell>
    );
  },
  (a, b) => {
    console.log("Are props equal?");
    return true;
  }
);
```

It only takes strings, booleans and numbers as an input. But I've added a cusom `isEqual` check to log, and for now forced it to always say it's equal. By my understanding, it should always return the cached component, and never re-render unless they key changes.

Here's where it's rendered, stripped of everything not functional:

```
const DataTableBody = (props: DataTableBodyProps) => (<FixedSizeList
          width={300}
          height={300}
          itemCount={props.rows.length}
          itemSize={35}
          outerRef={props.containerRef}
          outerElementType={CustomScrollbarsVirtualList}
        >
          {({ index, style }) => {
            const row = props.rows[index];
            props.prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <div
                style={{
                  ...style,
                  transform: `translate(${props.horizontalScroll}px, 0)`,
                  display: "flex"
                }}
              >
                {row.cells.map((cell: any) => (
                  <DataTableCell
                    key={cell.getCellProps().key}
                    value={cell.value}
                    header={cell.column.Header}
                    width={
                      props.widths[cell.column.Header] ||
                      props.defaultColumnWidth
                    }
                    isRepeatedValue={cell.isRepeatedValue}
                  />
                ))}
              </div>
            );
          }}
        </FixedSizeList>);
```

I logged the key (from `react-tables`), and it is a stable string unique for each cell.

When the prop `horizontalScroll` in the above example changes, which would change the `div`'s rendering, but shouldn't affect the `DataTableCell` as it's not passed in props, and the key hasn't changed - I get the console log `Rendering` printed out hundreds of time. I don't get `Are props equal?`

However, it works fine with scrolling the component! When scrolling vertically, the `style` will be changing, it re-renders, I see a whole load of `Are props equal?`, but only a handful of `Rendering` logs. I'm pretty confident the ones with a new key are being rendered, and existing keys are being checked for equality and NOT being rendered.

So why does it not work with `horizontalScroll`?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. It was react-window. Following their guide and passing `itemData` prop into the list, and avoiding using external values in the `RenderRow` prevented it recreating components:

https://react-window.now.sh/#/examples/list/memoized-list-items